# Django Can't Access Environment Variables

Tags: python, django

I have some environment variables that define API keys to be used in DJANGO. However, if I manually run my application using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

it works just fine. However, if I try with systemctl service it doesn't seem to read the variable. The webhook.service file is set to the same users. In the settings.py file the problematic line is:

```
'api_key':os.environ.get("APIKEY").
```

The api key is defined in /etc/environment. How can I get django to read these variables?

Comment: How are you defining your environment variable?

Comment: Please post what you're putting in `/etc/environment`

Comment: APIKEY=SG.n6GhBdsfsTNwH6Hg.RdsfdsLa7LLdQ7PjYyvXdUE84sdfsUGE